# Electronic SPDT signal selector

Tags: latch, toggle-switch

I'd like to make a circuit that switches between two inputs. When the control input is active I'd like the circuit to use the second input but when the control input isn't active I'd like it to use the first input.

Basically what I'm trying to do is use a channel of an RC quad-copter controller to allowing remote switching of quad-copter control between a gimbal controller and a flight controller.

Comment: Analog, digital, some kV? And how do you define active?

Comment: I define active as a current going through it, it's for an RC Quad copter which I'll be using one channel to switch between a gimbal controller and a flight controller. I could do this via Ardrino but was hoping for a cheaper alternative

Comment: unclear what you're asking Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @Colby: Please see my edit to your question and correct it if I've got anything wrong. For this circuit the signals are _inputs_. (You referred to them all as outputs without mentioning that they were outputs of some other circuits.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKxWOx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. CMOS two-way switch.*

With the sparse details supplied in your question I think that this circuit may satisfy your requirements.

A [CD4066](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4066b.pdf) quad CMOS switch can be used to switch analog voltages. Check the datasheet for details of on-resistance at the voltage you are operating on and pay particular attention if you are switching voltages which go down close to zero or the supply voltage.

**How it works**

- With CONTROL low SW1 is off and its output is high. This turns on SW2 and connects SOURCE1 to OUT. Meanwhile SW3 is open and SOURCE2 is isolated.
- When CONTROL is high SW1 turns on pulling the bottom of R1 to ground and turns off SW2 which isolates SOURCE1. Meanwhile SW3 closes and SOURCE2 is connected to OUT.

The trick in this circuit is using SW1 as a logic inverter, keeping the parts count low.